# Driver installation, failed to fetch cdrom://

Tags: debian, nvidia, steam

I'm kind of new to Debian/Linux OS. 
I just installed Debian 7.8 on my desktop.
And I seem to run into a lot of errors in the terminal.

I've been trying to install steam, nVidia drivers, but with no avail.

I have been searching Google for a few hours now for both installations, and it still fails me. Mainly because of the errors it gives me.

I did partitions automatically if that matters.

But **issue 1** is right here, whenever I try `aptitude update` I get the following,

```
root@debian:~# aptitude update

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20150110-14:41]/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache
```

(I couldn't post the full code since there were more than 2 links on it, and I'm  new here.)

So I searched the issue and it seems I need to edit my sources.list files. Which I can't edit because I don't have permission to do so. I seem to be the root user.

But this is not the only issue I have, **issue 2** is when installing the nVidia drivers.

```
you appear to be running a X server, please exit X before installing.
```

Whenever I try to shutdown the server with this code below, (I logged out as well and go in the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> logged in)  it didn't work.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

It gave me this

```
username is not in the sudoers file.
```

I hope someone can help me with this.. been searching for hours, I did read most of the guides, but it gives me errors.

Comment: I also added my name to the group in terminal, which didnt work either... i also added my username to the file when entering "Visudo" didnt work either.

Comment: What happens when you try to edit `sources.list`? Also, check out https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers for instructions on installing the NVIDIA drivers using Debian packages...

Comment: i cant save the file, because i have no permission. will give the debian installation another shot, since i tried it already. EDIT : it gives me this error when trying to save the sources.list file "gedit could not back up the old copy of the file before saving the new one. You can ignore this warning and save the file anyway, but if an error occurs while saving, you could lose the old copy of the file. Save anyway?" when i click save anyway it doesnt save it. it keeps popping back up.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `gedit` as `root`?

Comment: It worked now, ( Nvidia Drivers, ) they seem to be installed right now. But my first issue persists, whenever to run apt-get install X file name i get the first error as mentioned above.issue 1